# how to select html id which is assigned to Django variable in java script

Tags: javascript, django

I have an ID in html. This id is assigned to Django variable which contain ads ID. I want to add this ads ID to favorite list using local storage (cookies). Now, this ID is inside a loop and for every single ads will take different ID. The question is how to select the specific ID when the user click on that specific ID icons.

Here is my code:

```
{% for item in result %}
    <span id="favouriteBtn" style="color:#ccc" title="add this post to favorite list"> &#9734; </span>
{% endfor %}
```

THE ID SHOULD BE THIS WAY:

```
id={{item.id}}
```

Here is portion of javascript function:

```
$('#favouriteBtn').click(function(){
currentAddFav();
```

I want to set the ID as :

```
id={{item.id}}
```

and be able to select specific id which has been clicked by the user. How can i do that?

the currentAddFav function is as follow:

```
function currentAddFav(){
if(localStorage.getItem('favourites')){//If there are favourites
    var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage['favourites']);
    if (storage.indexOf('data-item-id') == -1) { 
      // # not found
      storage.push('data-item-id');
      localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(storage));
    } else {
      // # found
      console.log('item already in favorites')
    }

}           
else
{//No favourites in local storage, so add new
    var favArray= [];
    favArray.push('data-item-id');
    localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(favArray));
    console.log('New favourites list');
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an ID in HTML"?

Comment: not sure, but you can try id="{{ item.id }}". Its can select by jquery by $('#item.id')

Comment: I meant this id="{{item.id}}"

Comment: He cannot select it using "$('#item.id')" since he has arbitrary number of such elements, unless he dynamically generates his jQuery code using Django ofc.

Comment: Ngoc Pham, I tried your solution but it did not work. even when hover over the icon does not allow me to select or click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your span to have an attribute named 'data-item-id' which is equal to your item's id, like this:

```
{% for item in result %}
    <span id="favouriteBtn" onclick="currentAddFav({{ item.id }})" style="color:#ccc" title="add this post to favorite list"> &#9734; </span>
{% endfor %}
```

The "currentAddFav" function can handle the rest of the process (such as adding to Cookie, or whatever, from here.

Your "currentAddFav" function may look like this:

```
function currentAddFav(item_id){
    if (localStorage.getItem('favourites')) { // If there are favourites
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage['favourites']);
        if (storage.indexOf(item_id) == -1) { 
          // not found
          storage.push(item_id);
          localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(storage));
        } else {
          // found
          console.log('item already in favorites')
        }

    } else { // No favourites in local storage, so add new
        var favArray= [];
        favArray.push(item_id);
        localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(favArray));
        console.log('New favourites list');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nahiyan, Thanks for the response. I edited my question to include the currentAddFav function. The function is still not working. when I checked the console, no message is displayed when I clicked on favorite icon? any help or suggestion?

Comment: You need to take the value as an argument in your function "currentAddFav." That's the efficient way of doing it.

Comment: sorry, I did not get you?

Comment: Can you add your suggestion to the currentAddFav function ?

Comment: I edited my answer and included the "currentAddFav" function.

Comment: Nahiyan, I used your edited code and got this error "TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function".

Comment: For simplicity, I removed the separate jQuery code, my apologies. Embedded it in the span elements generated by the loop. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

```
{% for item in result %}
    <span id="{{ item.id }}" style="color:#ccc" title="add this post to favorite list"> &#9734; </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id_selected = "{{ item.id }}";
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

and when your page loading finish, you can add click function in this `var id_selected`

```
$('#' + id_selected).click(function () {
        currentAddFav();
});
```